# Oracle SQL - Trying to Add One Second to a Date I'm pulling from a text field

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

SQL newbie here.

In Oracle BI Publisher, I'm using Oracle SQL to do the following.

I need to pull only the time from a string and add one second to the time. The data in the 'Flight' column looks like this:

```
Dayton 01:23:59
```

I pull only the time using the following syntax:

```
substr(Flight,length(Flight)-8,8)
```

Which gives me this:

```
01:23:59
```

In the messy code below, I'm trying to add one second to the time which works but the second is '60' which is obviously is an invalid time.

```
 substr(lpad(to_number(replace(substr(Flight,length(Flight)-15,9),':')+2,'999999'),6,'0'),1,2)||':'||substr(lpad(to_number(replace(substr(Flight,length(Flight)-15,9),':')+2,'999999'),6,'0'),3,2)||':'||substr(lpad(to_number(replace(substr(Flight,length(Flight)-15,9),':')+2,'999999'),6,'0'),5,2)
```

Any ideas for a better way to do this?

Dan

Comment: You should make this two separate columns in your table; one for the location (type `VARCHAR2(n)`), one for the time (type `DATE`, as Oracle has no `TIME` data type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
 to_date(substr(Flight,length(Flight)-8,8), HH:MI:SS') + interval '1' second
```

Comment: That should be `'HH24:MI:SS'` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(FLIGHT, LENGTH(FLIGHT-8)), 'HH24:MI:SS') + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

or

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(FLIGHT, LENGTH(FLIGHT-8)), 'HH24:MI:SS') + 1 / 86400
```

because

```
   24 = hours in a day
 * 60 = minutes in an hour
 * 60 = seconds in a minute
-----
86400 = seconds in a day
```

After a while you find you've memorized numbers like that. :-)