# Oracle SQL - Using TO_DATE to add a second to a time pulled from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

This is building on the question I asked yesterday [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527397/oracle-sql-trying-to-add-one-second-to-a-date-im-pulling-from-a-text-field)

I'm pulling time from the 'Flight' column whose data looks like this:

```
Dayton 01:23:59
```

Which gives me this:

```
01:23:59
```

I then want to add 1 second to this. I'm using the following TO_DATE function:

```
to_date(substr(Flight,length(Flight)-8,8), HH:MI:SS') + interval '1' second
```

This works but the format includes the date:

```
2018-07-01T01:24:00.000+00:00
```

I need it to look like this:

```
01:24:00
```

I've tried using the SUBSTR to extract only the time to no avail.
Any ideas on how I can add 1 second to the above and preserve the HH24:MI:SS format?

Comment: Use `to_char()` to convert it back to a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that worked. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL - Trying to Add One Second to a Date I'm pulling from a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527397/oracle-sql-trying-to-add-one-second-to-a-date-im-pulling-from-a-text-field)

Answer (score 1):

The direct way is using `to_char` string conversion function with `HH24:MI:SS` pattern as

```
with t(myTime) as
(
 select to_date(substr('Dayton 01:23:59',length('Dayton 01:23:59')-8,9), 'HH:MI:SS') 
            + interval '1' second
   from dual
)
select to_char(myTime, 'hh24:mi:ss') as myTime_Chr from t;

MYDATE_CHR
01:24:00
```

or alternatively `regexp_replace` function maybe used as (*provided that the city name doesn't contain a digit*):

```
select regexp_replace('Dayton 01:24:00','[^0-9:]') as myTime 
  from dual;

MYTIME
01:24:00
```

*P.S. dual maybe replaced by your real table name.*

But seperating this column into two seperate columns as *city* and *time* is better.

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d7b13/607)